# WPF - binding rules on DataContext change?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Can anyone explain what are the rules of data binding on `DataContext` change for various modes of binding (`TwoWay`, `OneWay`, `OneTime`, `OneWayToSource`)?

Is it the source or target that is changed, or neither?

Answer (score 0):

just have a look at MSDN, it describes that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx

Comment: `OneWayToSource` - "Updates the source property when the target property changes." - but does it update the source when `DataContext` changes (and target property stays the same)? One might argue that it should...